# Email sending to unknown email fromn my ec2 instance

Tags: email

My application hosted in aws ec2 send email alert to its users when needed. While sending email alerts it also sends mail to unknown email id:

> Could not deliver message to the following recipient(s):
>
> Failed Recipient: j.gwire@yahoo.com Reason: Remote host said: 554
>   delivery error: dd This account has been temporarily suspended. Please
>   try again later. - mta1530.mail.ne1.yahoo.com

I changed email id, password everything. Still the issue is there.

Has my ec2 instance been hacked?

Comment: There are insufficient information in this question. Are you asking why it is trying to send mail to this user (we don't know your application, might be a hack or might be a feature) or why the delivery fails (message from server says it clearly). Also, what has the tag key-exchange to do with it, did you just randomly assign some tag you just found?

Comment: my application is an erp(odoo).j.gwire@yahoo.com unknown email id.i am asking why it is trying to send mail to this user(Not a feature,thinking like hacked).i randomly assigned tag because i am new user.

Comment: As a new user you should make yourself first familiar with this site and then you will hopefully realize that assigning a random tag just to continue is not the way you should ask here. Also, it is not possible to be sure if you are hacked, if this is an intended behavior of your ERP or if this is a misconfiguration of your ERP or if something else is going on on your machine. Thus look for other indicators of a possible compromise or misconfiguration and in doubt hire a security specialist and provide him access to your system for detailed analysis.

Comment: Your application sends email to users. Is that not an email address of a user?

Comment: We need the same type of info you would need when troubleshooting. You have offered no data. There is nothing we can do. You're seeing an email error. That's all you tell us.

Comment: It is not a e mail address of user,